# Mail not going if the URL call through Wget

Tags: php, email, cakephp, exec, wget

Recently i am working on a project where i need to get meta information, image information and other html element information of any website.

**Cakephp** is the framework i have used.  The code is pretty much straight forward having no complexity. So, when a user give some URL as input and hit Submit. The code crawl that given URL and get necessary information from that page and send a mail to the User with the information as a PDF.

Now complexity came when client ask to run the same **processes in the background**. This the code i have used to run in  background ..

```
// $this->sUrl Stores the client Input URL
// $this->noPages Stores the number of pages to be crawled from that website.
exec("wget -O - -b -q http://something.com/tools/checkerAction/".  base64_encode($this->sUrl)."/$this->noPages", $var);
```

When the run the code in background everything work just fine, i.e. the page is crawling properly, the PDF is generating healthy but the **MAIL** is not working.

Why? Is it because i have used a URL path [http://something.com/tools/checkerAction/] in **exec()** ??

I am getting no clue to fix this problem. Right now all i want to send my mail even if the process run in the background. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you think a listing of your mail-sending procedure would be more relevant?

Comment: @geomagas thanks for reply. Two things i want to mention here. First, i don't know how to do that. I.e. "listing of your mail-sending procedure". And 2nd, The same URL is also calling from a cron job. Do you think i can use your way in both cases?

Comment: I meant you should post the actual mail-sending procedure, instead of how you trigger it (exec wget etc).